# Salting and hash not working in php login

Tags: php, mysql, hash, salt

I am trying to learn PHP from O'Reilly (Robin Nixon) and the code written in that book is not working. I have already added the values to the database using this code

```
    $query = "CREATE TABLE users (
    forename VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    surname VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL)";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result) die($conn->error);*/

$salt1 = "qm&h*"; $salt2 = "pg!@";

$forename = 'Bill';
$surname = 'Smith';
$username = 'bsmith';
$password = 'mysecret';
$token = hash("ripemd128", "$salt1$password$salt2");

add_user($conn,$forename,$surname,$username,$token);

$forename = 'Pauline';
$surname = 'Jones';
$username = 'pjones';
$password = 'acrobat';
$token = hash('ripemd128', '$salt1$password$salt2');

add_user($conn,$forename,$surname,$username,$token);

function add_user($conn,$fn,$sn,$un,$pw) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$fn','$sn','$un','$pw')";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) die($conn->error);
}
```

And then when I try to login, it is giving me the error. For better understanding, I have customized the error statement and it is giving me error1. I also tried to store password in database without using hash and salting and after that when I tried to login without using hash and salting, it worked perfectly fine, that proves that the problem is with either hash or salting or both. I am using the following code according the book.

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) &&
    isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
{
    $un_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $pw_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un_temp'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        die($conn->error);
    } elseif($result->num_rows) {
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
        $result->close();
        $salt1 = "qm&h*"; $salt2 = "pg!@";
        $token = hash("ripemd128", "$salt1$pw_temp$salt2");

        if ($token == $row[3]) {
            echo "$row[0] $row[1] : Hi $row[0], you are now logged in as '$row[2]'";
        } else {
            die("error1 - Invalid username/password combination");
        }
    } else {
        die("error2 - Invalid 2 username/password combination");
    }
} else {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die("Please enter your username and password");
}
$conn->close();

function mysql_entities_fix_string($conn, $string) {
    return htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($conn, $string));
}
function mysql_fix_string($conn, $string) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
    return $conn->real_escape_string($string);
}
?>
```

Comment: 1) Use prepared statements, 2) don't do your own hashing, use the [Password API](http://php.net/password). 3) Don't modify users passwords to put into the DB, or retrieving.

Comment: @JonStirling I did not get your comment. I am write now on beginner level. Please specify.

Comment: Please see the examples on [mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), the password API I already linked to, you want to be looking at password_hash and password_verify functions.

Comment: @JonStirling Ok, I will look into that but why above code is not working ? According to the book it should work. I've written same as it is written in the book.

Comment: Probably because single quotes are literal strings, variables are not interpolated. So when you have `'$salt1$password$salt2'` you probably meant to have `"$salt1$password$salt2"` for example.

Comment: @JonStirling Nope, I tried it with double quotes and it does not work

Comment: Update the code in your question with your updated code.

Comment: @JonStirling I've updated it.

Comment: You've still got them in your create user script... This did not come from a book.

Comment: @JonStirling So should I need to update database to store password using hash and salting using double quotes ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you're hashing the string `$salt1$password$salt2` not the actual salt + password.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes, it worked. Thanks

Comment: Gdgd, but please do fix the stuff I mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: @JonStirling Done

Answer (score 0):

I had used some code to store password in My SQL using hash and salt try using that,

```
$salt="pg!@";
$password="abcd";(for example)
$password_salt = $password.$salt;
$password_hash = hash('sha256', $password_salt);
u can use this password hash in your query for storing password.

Hope it helps
```

Comment: Hash algorithms of the SHA-* family are not appropriate to hash passwords, they are way too fast and can be brute-forced too easily. Please switch to the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function instead.